# How could I close form?

Tags: c#

When I click button from Form 1, the data of form 2 will display. So, I click button from form 1 again. The next data will add in new form 2, but form before still display. Therefore I have 2 form display. How could I close form before and display next form?

Comment: Can u show what have u tried so far??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this, you need to store the reference to your form and manipulate with it.

**What you want** - close `Form2` every time and open again:

```
public class Form1
{
    private Form2 _form2;

    public Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_form2 != null)
        {
            _form2.Close();
        }

        _form2 = new Form2();
        _form2.Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); // or any other actions with form
        _form2.Show();
    }
}
```

It will close the previously used form and create a new one every time.

**What you can also do** - reuse this form and add some kind of "close form" button:

```
public class Form1
{
    private Form2 _form2;

    public Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_form2 == null)
        {
            _form2 = new Form2();
            _form2.Show();
        }

        _form2.Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); // or any other actions with form
    }

    public Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // close button
    {
        if (_form2 != null) { 
            _form2.Close(); 
            _form2 = null; 
        }
    }
}
```

It will simply create a form at first time, and then just change its text when you click your button.

Comment: thank you, i tried and it runned